# Difference between a default post type and a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, post-type-support

I'm a new user of WP, i have create 6 customs post type where i can change parameters of them in the functions.php of my personnal theme. I can change 'supports' and 'slug'. On my url if i put my cpt label like mysite.fr/editos/ i got the list of my all cpt edito post.
I want to use the default post type of WP which is "post", but i want to change the 'supports' and 'slug' and get the same function of listing like above

How can I do that ?
If it's not possible i will create a new cpt.

Regards

Comment: So you want a `post` archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to Shaikh Aezaz

> Yes you can, check this for reference:
>   developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box – Shaikh
>   Aezaz

Comment: By your message, I can guess you only need title, editor, and comment metabox and want to remove other meta boxes? If so, you can remove other metabox with the "remove_meta_box" filter

Comment: Yes it's that but can i do it just for a specific psot-type ?

Comment: Yes you can, check this for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/

Comment: Thanks you it works nice

Answer (score 0):

Every archive is a posts archive, the main post archive being the homepage, if you want to move posts to a different URL, you can go to the readins settings and declare a page to be the posts page. Note that this page then acts as a placeholder purely for slug/URL purposes. You can't change its page template to change the template of that page.

Additionally, there are the options on the permalinks page, posts also have date archives.

But everything else is the same as custom post types, and taxonomy archives work identically for both